# Deleting GAE application version programmatically

Tags: google-app-engine

There is a way to delete the oldest version of a GAE application programmatically?

Update: [Now is possible to delete old versions of you app using appcgf](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2723#makechanges).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no api to delete deployed versions programmatically.